# Express-validator not validating req.body when working with image upload (multer)

Tags: node.js, express, multer, express-validator

I have a form where I have fields such as location, age and image. I am sending these three fields in the formData.

```
 location: 'Location 1',
 age: 23,
 image: (binary)
```

In the backend I am using express and express-validator for validating the form fields.

```
var imageUpload= multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/top-level')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname.split('.')[0] + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
      }
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'), false);
    }
  }
});

module.exports = { imageUpload};
```

I first tried with this

```
router.post('/someroute', [isLoggedIn], create);
```

and here is `create` function for actual logic

```
const create = async (req, res, next) => {
  fileUploadNow(req, res, async function(err) { // uploading file

    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send(unExpectedError(
        'Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!',
        'Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!',
        'image'
      ))
    }


    check('location').isLength({ min: 3, max: 35}).withMessage('name must be at least 3 or maximum 35 characters long').trim().escape();
    check('age').isInt().withMessage('should be a number');

    const errors = await validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: 'Got error while submitting',
        data: errors.array()
      });
    }

    if (!req.file) { 
      return res.status(422).send(unExpectedError(
        'Please select a thumbnail',
        'Please select a thumbnail',
        'image'
      ))
    }
    try {
      let image_path = config.SERVER_URL + '/' + req.file.filename;
      const {location, age} = req.body;

      let obj = {
        location: semester_name,
        slug: image_path,
        age: age
      }

      let result = await knex('table').insert(obj).returning('*');
      if (result) {

        return res.status(200).send({
          message: 'successfull',
          data: result
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(422).send(unExpectedError(
        'Something went wrong, please try to add details again',
        'Something went wrong, please try to add semester details again',
        'semester'
      ))
    }
  })
}
```

With this code I am able to handle error for image field and **I am able to show image errors to user** but not for data that are coming in `req.body`. may be we need to do check req.body validation part only in the route middleware.

Then I tried to change like this

router.post('/someroute', [isLoggedIn, imageUpload, Validation], create); // I imported these two

and `Validation` function

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const Validation= [
  check('location').isLength({ min: 3, max: 35}).withMessage('name must be at least 3 or maximum 35 characters long').trim().escape(),
    check('age').isInt().withMessage('should be a number')
];

module.exports = { Validation}
```

In `create` function shown above, I removed the fileUploadNow function and kept only logic part. Now in this everything works I am getting the error that are being generated by req.body, and also I am getting the image error in browser console **(500 status code)** if not correct image type selected but I am not able to handle image error which mean **I am not able to show it to users**. How do I handle and show errors to user for image and req.body part